# How to express functors in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, functor, code-translation

I'm translating an application from C++ to .NET/C#. However I'm struggling on how to express C++ functors in C#.

What would be the best way to translate the following expression to C#?

```
struct AircraftMover
{
    AircraftMover(float vx, float vy)
    : velocity(vx, vy)
    {
    }

    void operator() (Aircraft& aircraft, sf::Time) const
    {
        aircraft.accelerate(velocity);
    }

    sf::Vector2f velocity;
};
```

Comment: `Func<Aircraft, Time> MakeAircraftMover(float vx, float vy) { Vector2f velocity = new velocity(vx, vy); return (a, t) => a.accelerate(velocity); }`

Comment: Please show what you've tried. SO is not a free code translation service.

Comment: do you mean operator instead of function?

Comment: @tnw ok, that made me laugh!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes wouldn't it be an Action<Aircraft,Time> since the lambda expression doesn't return a value? Then, where would you encapsulate that function?

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez oh, true. My C# got a bit rusty. The gist is that member variables become function local variables, and op() is a lambda. The C# compiler will then, behind the scenes, promote the captured local variables to members of a class similar to the original in C++, and the lambda to a method in that class :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the functor with a lambda in the C++ code, then use an equivalent lambda in the C# code.

**Edit:** Your C++ code from the comments modified to use lambdas:

```
void Player::initializeActions() {
  const float playerSpeed = 200.f;
  mActionBinding[MoveLeft].action =
      derivedAction<Aircraft>([=](Aircraft& a, Time) { a.accelerate(Vector2f(-playerSpeed, 0.f)); });
  ...
}
```

The equivalent C# code would look something like:

```
mActionBinding[MoveLeft].action = 
    new derivedAction<Aircraft>((Aircraft a, Time t) => a.accelerate(new Vector2f(-playerSpeed, 0.f)));
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your solution? I'm unable to visualize it :S.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the functor is used in the C++ code?

Comment: Yep, here's the use of how the functor is used.

void Player::initializeActions()
{
 const float playerSpeed = 200.f;

 mActionBinding[MoveLeft].action  = derivedAction<Aircraft>(AircraftMover(-playerSpeed, 0.f));
 mActionBinding[MoveRight].action = derivedAction<Aircraft>(AircraftMover(+playerSpeed, 0.f));
 mActionBinding[MoveUp].action    = derivedAction<Aircraft>(AircraftMover(0.f, -playerSpeed));
 mActionBinding[MoveDown].action  = derivedAction<Aircraft>(AircraftMover(0.f, +playerSpeed));
}

Comment: template <typename GameObject, typename Function>
std::function<void(SceneNode&, sf::Time)> derivedAction(Function fn)
{
 return [=] (SceneNode& node, sf::Time dt)
 {
  // Check if cast is safe
  assert(dynamic_cast<GameObject*>(&node) != nullptr);

  // Downcast node and invoke function on it
  fn(static_cast<GameObject&>(node), dt);
 };
}

Comment: Your solution is ok, but it needs the class types in the (a,t) in order to call the accelerate method.

Comment: Modified to add the explicit types.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Action like this:

```
Action<Aircraft, Time> airCraftMover = (a,t) => a.Accelerate(new Velocity(vx, vy));
```

This can then be passed around and applied to Aircraft at will.

To use it on an Aircraft, just call the Action like a method:

```
airCraftMover(aircraft, time);
```